# how to loop a collection inside a collection in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

i want to list all the images for each project, i tried to do it like this, but it always return 1 image only.

```
public function home()
{
    $projects = Project::all(); //result : 1

    foreach($projects as $project){
        $images = $project->images()->get(); 
        // dd($images); //result : 4
        foreach($images as $image){
            return '<img src="'.$image->image_path.'">';
        }
    }
}
```

the code above is just for test purpose, what i want to do is to display it in a table, something like this in my controller :

```
<tbody>
'
$images = $project->images()->get();
foreach($images as $image){
'
<tr>
<td><img src="'.$image->image_path.'"></td>
</tr>
'
}
'
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a function can only return once, you probably need to do something different on the inner foreach like concatenating the image html to an existing string.

That said, the *right* way to do this would generally be to return $images to be used directly in a template where you would build out the html.

Comment: yes its just for test purpose, i will display it in a table, i just dont know how to loop the $images variable inside $projects variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what all is going on here, but it looks like you want to do something that is relatively simple in Laravel if you are able to use Controllers and Blade Templates.

First, you start with your controller (keep all of your application logic there):

```
// ProjectController.php
public function home()
{
    //-- grab all the projects, with all of their images

    // Using with() will allow you to eager load those images
    // from the database if they are Eloquent relationships.
    $projects = Project::with('images')->get();

    //-- send those $projects to your view

    // Using with() here will send that variable to your
    // view accessible by the key.
    return view('projects')->with(['projects' => $projects]);
}
```

Then, in your blade template, you can easily iterate over the projects and images:

```
// views/projects.blade.php

@foreach($projects as $project)
<table>
...
  <tbody>
    @foreach($project->images as $image)
      <tr>
        <td><img src="{{ $image->image_path }}"></td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
...
</table>
@endforeach

</tbody>
```

Hope this helps. If none of this makes sense, you can always check out the docs, they are really well written!

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2)

Be sure to check out the Controllers, Blade Templates and Eloquent ORM - Relationships sections :)

Comment: i'm returning a datatable from my controller to a view, in one of the column i want to list all the image with a table.

Comment: I would still recommend using Blade Templating if you are able (even using @include to a partial for the datatable, maybe?). Building out HTML in the Controller tends to be error prone.

However, if you simply want to fix the "only 1 image being returned" problem, @Project707's answer is correct. Instead of `return`ing the value in the images foreach, echo out the value or concatenate it to the end of a variable.